# awk dynamic string matching

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have two files - (a) one from which I get a name and the file in which the name occurs and (b) the actual file on which I want to match the name and get two words before and after it.

Snapshot of first file

```
Ito 65482.txt
David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold 73586.txt
David Jones 73586.txt
Jacob FleUchbautr 73586.txt
```

The name is a string separated by spaces as above.

Snapshot of file 65482.txt (it contains garbled OCR text)

```
nose just brnukiiitt tip tinwallfin the golden 
path of Ito etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli the trees 
Butt It as tie not intra and plcturosiiiicness 
limit wo were of m that is not altogether We 
and hunting and llslilng In plenty anti lit lIly
```

Desired output in the format

```
Ito path of etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli
```

i.e. Two words before and after the match.

```
#!/bin/bash
fPath='/Users/haimontidutta/Research/IIITD/Aayushee/Code/Source-Code/Thesis/src/ReputedPersonDetection/data/OutputofNERFinal_v1a.txt'
echo "Enter Script"

while IFS=' ' read -ra arr
do 
 fname="${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}"
 #echo $fname
 name=""
 for((idx=0; idx<$[${#arr[@]}-1]; ++idx))
 do
  name=$name" ${arr[idx]}"
 done
 #echo $name 
 filepath='/Users/haimontidutta/Research/IIITD/Aayushee/Code/Source-Code/Thesis/src/ReputedPersonDetection/data/final/'$fname
 #echo $fName
 #echo $filepath

 #Extract window around name
 awk -v nm="$name" '{
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     {
       #print $i 
       if($i~$nm)
       {
        print nm OFS  $(i-2) OFS $(i-1) OFS $(i+1) OFS $(i+2); exit;
      }}}' $filepath
done < $fPath
```

I am able to extract the name and filepath, but in the awk statement the dynamic matching of the name is failing and the window cannot be obtained.

How do I do this?

Comment: You probably want `$i~nm` rather than `$i~$nm`

Comment: I tried $i~nm - it executes, but generates no output.

Comment: The name match should be "David Juno" and not to just " Juno".

Comment: Full match of name is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    file = $NF
    name = $1 (NF>2 ? " " $2 : "")
    if ( !(file in file2names) && ((getline line < file) > 0) ) {
        close(file)
        ARGV[ARGC++] = file
    }
    file2names[file][name]
    next
}
{
    $0 = " " $0 " "
    for (name in file2names[FILENAME]) {
        if ( pos = index($0," "name" ") ) {
            split(substr($0,1,pos),bef)
            split(substr($0,pos+length(name)+1),aft)
            print name, bef[1], bef[2], aft[1], aft[2]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Ito path of etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli
```

If you actually want all pre-filename strings from "file" to be part of the name instead of just the first 1 or 2 strings (see the comments below) then just change:

```
name = $1 (NF>2 ? " " $2 : "")
```

to this in gawk:

```
name = gensub(/\s+\S+$/,"",1)
```

or this in any awk:

```
name = $0
sub(/ +[^ ]+$/,"",name)
```

With any other awk you'd just store the names for a file as a space-separated string, e.g. instead of `file2names[file][name]` you'd do `file2names[file] = (file in file2names ? file2names[file] FS : "") name` and then split them before looping, e.g. instead of `for (name in file2names[file])` you'd do `split(file2names[FILENAME],names); for (name in names)`

The input `file` above is just the first file in your example.

Comment: This will only match one or two word names (like "Ito" or "David Jones"), not longer names ("David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold").   Use something like `file=$NF; NF--; name=$0` instead.

Comment: @cas: right, but it remains unclear from the question whether _everything_ preceding $NF in "file" should be considered the "name" or not.

Comment: @Cbhihe it's very clear that the file contains a name (with one or more words in the name) and a filename, with the filename being the last field.  There's nothing in the question to even suggest that only the first 1 or 2 words of the name are needed.   That notion seems to have been introduced by some comments confusing the input file format with the two words (before & after) wanted in the output.  Even the OP's sh code is extracting the name from all but the last field, which directly contradicts that notion.

Comment: @cas: Reviewed OP's code: ` for((idx=0; idx<$[${#arr[@]}-1]; ++idx)); do name=$name" ${arr[idx]}"; done` ... You were right.

Comment: @cas Unlike `NF++`, `NF--` is undefined behavior per POSIX. Some awks will delete that last field, others will ignore it, others still could so anything else. The OP specifically only wants 1 or 2 word names, see the comments under the question - when asked about the line containing "David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold" they said "David Juno" should be matched. Obviously it's a trivial tweak (`sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"")`), if I'm misreading that but the OP has accepted by answer so I think I got it right.

Comment: @Cbhihe you can't assume by reading code that doesn't do what the OP wants that that code implements any part of their requirements correctly. The OP is trying to find names, IMHO it's unlikely (but not impossible I admit) that `Ilrcwrry` is part of someones name and so that in combination with the comment from the OP under the question about only wanting to match `David Juno` when the only line containing that name is `David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold 73586.txt` is what makes me think they only want to match 1 or 2 word names. But I could be wrong and it's an easy tweak if the OP wants all words.

Answer (score 1):

Given input files:

```bsh
$ cat first.file
Ito 65482.txt
David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold 73586.txt
David Jones 73586.txt
Jacob FleUchbautr 73586.txt

$ cat 65482.txt
nose just brnukiiitt tip tinwallfin the golden
path of Ito etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli the trees
Butt It as tie not intra and plcturosiiiicness
limit wo were of m that is not altogether We
and hunting and llslilng In plenty anti lit lIly

$ cat 73586.txt
Lorem ipsum David Jones dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non ultrices tellus. Donec porttitor sodales mattis. Nulla eu ante eget libero dictum accumsan nec non odio. Nullam lobortis porttitor mauris a feugiat. Vestibulum ultrices ipsum at maximus consequat. Vivamus molestie Jacob FleUchbautr tortor ac felis varius gravida. Cras accumsan dolor at velit sodales auctor. Vestibulum sit amet scelerisque eros, quis porta orci. Donec eget erat dolor. Integer id vestibulum massa. Quisque lacus risus, venenatis nec euismod nec, ultrices sed mi. Proin tincidunt ipsum mattis lectus pulvinar interdum. Suspendisse convallis justo iaculis, semper nisl at, imperdiet ante.
# ..........^^^^^^^^^^^..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then:

```bsh
mapfile -t files < <(awk '{print $NF}' first.file | sort -u)

word='[^[:blank:]]+'

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    mapfile -t names < <(grep -wF "$file" first.file | sed -E 's/ [^ ]+$//')
    pattern="($word $word) ($(IFS='|'; echo "${names[*]}")) ($word $word)"
    declare -p file pattern
    grep -oE "$pattern" "$file" | sed -E "s/$pattern/\\2 \\1 \\3/"
done
```

outputs

```
declare -- file="65482.txt"
declare -- pattern="([^[:blank:]]+ [^[:blank:]]+) (Ito) ([^[:blank:]]+ [^[:blank:]]+)"
Ito path of etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli
declare -- file="73586.txt"
declare -- pattern="([^[:blank:]]+ [^[:blank:]]+) (David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold|David Jones|Jacob FleUchbautr) ([^[:blank:]]+ [^[:blank:]]+)"
David Jones Lorem ipsum dolor sit
Jacob FleUchbautr Vivamus molestie tortor ac
```

That regular expression *requires* 2 words to appear before and after the name. If the name appears at the start or end of the line, no match.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `awk`, but IMO is much easier to do in `perl`.  And that's even before you consider that there are over 800 perl library modules for various natural language processing tasks in [Lingua::*](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Lingua%3A%3A), which is what you seem to be doing.

The following perl script first builds up a commonly used perl data structure called a Hash-of-Arrays (HoA) using the filenames as the **keys** to the an associative array (aka `hash`), and each key's **values** being an indexed array of names.   See `man perldsc` for more info on HoA and other perl data structures.

The `%files` HoA would end up with data like:

```
{
  "65482.txt" => ["Ito"],
  "73586.txt" => ["David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold", "David Jones", "Jacob FleUchbautr"],
}
```

It also uses an array called `@order` to remember the order in which each filename was seen, so that they can be processed later in the same order (this is often useful because perl hashes, as in many other languages, are inherently unordered.  If you don't care about the order, you can just iterate over the keys of the hash instead)

If a filename does not exist, it prints a warning message to STDERR and skips to the next line of the "first" file.   The `print STDERR ...` line can be deleted or commented out if you don't want the warnings, or just redirect stderr to /dev/null when you run it.

Once it has finished building the `%files` HoA, it opens each file for read, creates and pre-compiles a regular expression matching any of the names wanted for that particular file, and prints every line matching the RE.

The regular expressions it builds would end up with values like:

```
(((\w+\s+){2})(David Juno Ilrcwrry Hold|David Jones|Jacob FleUchbautr)((\s+\w+){2}))
```

The reason for doing it this way is so that each filename only has to be processed **once**, and each line of each file only has to be examined once to see if it matches one of the names.  If you have many files and/or if they are very large, this results in an enormous performance boost over the naive approach of reading and matching every line of every file repeatedly, once for every name listed in the "first" file - e.g. if you had 1000 files with 1000 lines each, and a total of 50 names to match, the naive method would have to read and match a line 50 million times (files * lines * names) instead of just 1 million times (files * lines)

The script is set up to make it easy to choose how to match the words before and after a matched name.  Un-comment **only** one of the two `my $count=` lines in the script.  The first strictly requires exactly two words before AND after each name - this is already un-commented.  The second is relaxed about how many words can exist before or after a name (from 0 to 2).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
my %files = ();
my @order = ();

# Un-comment only one of the following two lines.
my $count=2;
#my $count='0,2';

# First, build up a HoA where the key is the filename and
# the value is an array of names to match in that file.
while(<>) {
  s/^\s+|\s+$//;   # strip leading and trailing spaces
  next if (m/^$/); # skip empty lines
  my ($name,$filename) = m/^(.*)\s+(.*)$/; # extract name and filename

  # warn about and skip filenames that don't exist
  if (! -e $filename) {
    print STDERR "Error found on $ARGV, line $.: '$filename' does not exist.";
    next;
  };

  # remember the order we first see each filename.
  push @order, $filename unless ( defined($files{$filename}) );

  # Add the name to the %files HoA
  push @{ $files{$filename} }, $name;
};

# Process each file once only, in order.
foreach my $filename (@order) {
  open(my $fh,"<",$filename) || die "Error opening $filename for read: $!\n";

  my $re = "(((\\w+\\s+){$count})(" .           # two words
           join('|',@{ $files{$filename} }) .   # the names
           ")((\\s+\\w+){$count}))";            # and two words again

  $re = qr/$re/;  # add an 'i' after '/' for case-insensitive

  while(<$fh>) {
    if (m/$re/) {
      my $found = join(" ",$4,$2,$5);
      $found =~ s/\s\s+/ /g;
      print $found
    };
  };
}
```

Save as, e.g. `match.pl` and make executable with `chmod +x match.pl`, and run like:

```
$ ./match.pl first.txt 
Error found on first.txt line 2: '73586.txt' does not exist.
Error found on first.txt line 3: '73586.txt' does not exist.
Error found on first.txt line 4: '73586.txt' does not exist.
Ito path of etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli
```

BTW, it's not what you asked for, but I'd recommend printing the matching name separated from the found words with a colon (`:`) or anything other than a space.  A tab is good too.  This will make it much easier to parse the output file with other programs.  i.e.

```
Ito:path of etmlmbimiiit tlmmgli
```

You can do this by changing the `my $found =`  line to:

```
my $found = "$4:" . join(" ",$2,$5);
```

or

```
my $found = "$4\t" . join(" ",$2,$5);
```

Comment: With respect to `This can be done in awk, but IMO is much easier to do in perl` - you keep posting about things being hard to do in awk when they aren't, please consider the possibility that you just are more familiar with perl and so may not be aware of the simple ways to do some tasks in awk. I find it vastly easier to do anything in awk than perl but I know that's because of my unfamiliarity with perl, not because of the tool/language.

Comment: @EdMorton The reason I keep saying that is because it's true.  Many things **are** easier in perl, **much** easier, because perl has built-in functions (like join and map and splice) that make string and array handling easier - no need to write your own join function, or rewrite the same tedious `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)` loops all the time.   And then, there's the huge library of CPAN modules - how many lines of awk code would it take my own CSV or JSON or XML or HTML parser, for example - a lot more than just `use Text::CSV`, `use JSON`, etc.  **Nothing** like CPAN exists for awk.

Comment: Please consider that YOU are just unfamiliar with perl.  I'm very familiar with both awk (~30 years) and perl (25+ years), and know the strengths and limitations of both.   There really are many things that are trivially easy to do in perl, that require significantly more effort copy/pasting & editing, or just retyping, the same boiler-plate code that you've used in that last few hundred awk scripts.  I still write a lot more awk than perl, but mostly for simple stuff of a dozen lines or so.  Anything more complex I'll do in perl because I can do it in a fraction of the time.

Comment: BTW, I didn't say "hard to do in awk".  I said "much easier to do in perl".  Those two sentences have different meanings.   What I generally think about it is "some things are a PITA to do in awk, but not in perl".    And I tell people "use perl" when it's appropriate for exactly the same reasons I tell people "use awk, not a shell while read loop" when that is appropriate.  Use the right/best tool for the job.

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't things that are easier to do in perl, I'm saying that you keep claiming specific things are hard to do in awk (or easier to do in perl if you prefer) that simply aren't.

Comment: Thanks much for both the solutions in awk and perl. It helped resolve the issue I was having. I learnt a lot with this exercise!

Comment: @EdMorton i refer you to my comment above: `I didn't say "hard to do in awk". I said "much easier to do in perl". Those two sentences have different meanings.`.  You keep saying I said something that I didn't.  Stop doing that.

Comment: @HaimontiDutta cool, teaching useful stuff was the reason I posted my answer.  It's why I put in the effort to explain what the script does and how it does it and why - that's more important than just the code.

Comment: @cas: +1 your solution is excellent and your very didactic introduction/explanation of it is the next thing beyond excellent.

Comment: @cas in **this** answer you said "harder in awk than perl" when it isn't, in other answers and comments recently you've said "hard to do in awk" when it isn't. [I said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649593/awk-dynamic-string-matching/649689?noredirect=1#comment1218591_649689) "you **keep** posting about things being hard to do in awk when they aren't" which is 100% true - you clearly DO keep posting about things being hard to do in awk when they aren't which is your prerogative of course but you're usually wrong and so it makes you look ill-informed.

Comment: And I don't need to consider that I'm unfamiliar with perl, I specifically said in my first comment that I'm unfamiliar with perl. You've never seen me say anything was hard in perl or harder than it is in awk for that reason, I simply don't know perl well enough to judge and, again, perl and awk aren't peers anyway, perl is more of a peer for shell+tools.

Comment: @EdMorton Do you have problems understanding plain English?   "easier in perl" is **NOT** the same as "hard in awk", so stop putting YOUR words in MY mouth by claiming that it is.  This is now the third time I've pointed out my **exact** words and what they mean to you, and you're still claiming that I said something that I didn't.   I wasn't interested the first time, and now I'm actively bored of your false pedantry.  Please go pester someone else.

Comment: You KNOW you recently said deleting a field is hard to do in awk and I showed how to easily do it in awk and that's just 1 example. That's fine, I thought maybe I could open your eyes to the possibility that maybe you don't know awk as well as you think you do but you just keep posting about things being "hard to do in awk" or "easier in perl than awk" and I'll just keep posting concise awk solutions that show you're wrong like I did with my answer here.

Comment: 1. Go away.  2. Stop pestering me.  3.  I'm pretty sure I said "deleting a field is a PITA in awk", not that it's "hard".  Which is a fact that is undeniably true. It **is** a PITA.  Deleting a field (or an array element) should be a standard feature of a language, not some stupid hack of forcing the interpreter to re-split the input line because that's the only way it can kludge it.  You'll never cure your splice() envy by denying it.  4. Go away and stop pestering me.  5. See points 1, 2, and 4. And 5 again, since you seem to have difficulty understanding what I say.

Comment: @cas I didn't plan to respond again as you're getting defensive but I just noticed above you said `how many lines of awk code would it take my own CSV or JSON or XML or HTML parser, for example - a lot more than just use Text::CSV, use JSON, etc. Nothing like CPAN exists for awk.`. Again you're showing you don't know awk as well as you think you do. GNU awk has libraries for all of those except HTML. `CPAN` appears to be a repository for perl extensions, if so the equivalent is the gawk extensions library at http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: And before you say "oh but perl has thousands of extensions while awk only has about 20" - that is again because awk and perl are not peers. Awk has the extensions it needs to be useful for its sole intended purpose of manipulating text. If there was some need for another extension, then someone would create and share that other extension in the library.

Comment: 1. It's amazing how your great god POSIX isn't the be-all and end-all when you're trying to "win" your annoying argument/harassment. 2. I'm well aware of GNU awk's extension API and tiny lib collection, I've even posted answers here using them.  3. Your understanding of what CPAN is is basic, at best. 4. By your own admission, you don't know perl - your opinion of perl is therefore worthless.  5. I know both awk and perl - my opinion of both is backed by knowledge and experience.   6. "awk and perl are not peers" - back to POSIX worship, now that it's convenient.  7. Go away, stop bothering me

Comment: RE: grasping at straws, or gawkextlib: Wow, you found **THE** answer to CPAN.  17 total library modules and one base library, over the 15+ years since the xgawk projext started (folded into gawk 4.1).  One of them (csv) "not released yet". another (mpfr) tagged as "experimental".    RE: "*sole intended purpose of manipulating text*" - yeah, like gd, haru, lmdb, pgsql, and redis. almost a third of the total 17 gawkext libs. abort, errno, select aren't text manipulation, either. 7 of 17 nothing to do with text.  mpfr reclen, and timex aren't, strictly speaking, text manipulation either.

Comment: RE: (paraphrased) "someone would write it if needed" - no, they haven't, and likely never will.  The primary reason for using awk is that it is (almost) guaranteed to be everywhere with very few (and very minor) incompatibilities between implementations.  Once you abandon that, you may as well use perl and the tens of thousands of modules in CPAN (pretty much any useful thing you can imagine, not only "would" be written, but actually **has**). Or some other language, that isn't awk.